# Unnecessary proofs?

Tags: geometry, alternative-proof

I've been reading a book, and in the geometry section, it gives what seem to me unnecessary and complicated proofs for simple facts.

For example:

> $D,E,F$ are the feet of the altitudes from $A,B,C$ of $\Delta ABC$. Prove that $AD+BE+CF<AB+BC+AC$
>
> **Proof**:
>
> In $\Delta ABD$, $AD<AB$. In $\Delta ADC$, $AD<AC$. Adding, we get $2AD<AB+AC$.
>
> Similarly, $2BE<AB+BC$ and $2CF<AC+BC$. Adding, we get $2(AD+BE+CF)<2(AB+BC+AC)$. Dividing by 2, we get the required result.

This seems to me unnecessary. Why not just use $AD<AB,BE<BC,CF<AC$ and add to get the required result?

Another one, in proving that $AB-AC<BC$, takes a similarly long winded approach, constructing $D$ on $AC$ such that $AB=AD$ and then going from there. I just used the triangle inequality, $AB<AC+BC$, and subtracting $AC$ from both sides.

Is there something wrong with my approach? Why does this book, and a lot of other books on the market, give such proofs?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: Hmm... I would argue that $D$ could be either $B$ or $C$ and it possible that $AD = AB$ but that can't hold for all three lengths.   But the books approach does not address or solve that at all.  So... I don't know.  Seems like you are doing fine.  (Maybe this is how the book is actually proving the triangle inequality in the first place... But that seems dubious and ham-fisted.)

Comment: I agree with @fleablood that the proofs should handle equality. The book proof should have said that $AD\le AC$, $AD\le AB$, they can't both reach equality simultaneously, and hence $2AD < AB+AC$, etc. In your version you should also have $\le$ everywhere: $AD\le AB$, $BE\le BC$, $CF\le AC$, and then show that they can't all be equal simultaneously. It seems to me that the book proof is a corrupted copy of a correct and complete proof.

Comment: How *is* the triangle inequality taught in basic geometry? It's axiomatic that two points determine a straight line and a unique distance.  But is it axiomatic that a line segment extended by another will be a greater then the distance between the endpoints of a three point path?  Perhaps by introduces right triangles and hypotenuse longer than legs is the texts way of proving the triangle inequality?

Comment: Ok.... I think these are all steps in the way to proving i) that a perpendicular/altitude is the shortest distance between a point and a line and ii) the triangle inequality.  Compare this to Euclid's Elements Book I Propisitions 16 through 20 (https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI20.html).  Prop 20 *is* the triangle inequality.  Out of context it's hard to see the gyst of their direction but it looks kind of botched to me.

Comment: I am not sure that all claims are true for obtuse triangles.